# else if executes executes automatically before asking for user input

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ programming, I would like to create a program to find area, volume of shapes I used switch case to select shapes and used else if inside switch for selecting area or volume but it executes only one switch statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include<math.h>
#define PI 3.14159

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double radius;
    double square;
    double qube;
    double quboid;
    double cylinder;
    double sphere;
    double a;
    double length;
    double breadth;
    double height;
    double width;
    char userchoice1;
    char userchoice;

    cout << "Select any shape by typing the no correctly\n";
    cout << "1-square\n";
    cout << "2-Cube\n";
    cout << "3-Cuboid\n";
    cout << "4-Circle\n";
    cout << "5-Sphere\n";
    cout << "6-rectangle\n";

    cout << "Select any shape by typing the no correctly\n";
    cin >> userchoice;

    switch (userchoice) {
        case '1':
            cout << "3-area\n";
            cout << "4-perimeter\n";
            if (userchoice = 3) {
                cout << "Enter side a\n";
                cin >> a;
                cout << "Area of square is " << a * a << "sq.units" << endl;
            } else if (userchoice = 4) {
                cout << "Enter side\n";
                cin >> a;
                cout << "Perimeter of square is " << 4 * a << "sq.units" << endl;
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << "1-area\n";
            cout << "2-volume\n";
            if (userchoice = 1) {
                cout << "Enter side a\n";
                cin >> a;
                cout << "Area of cube is " << 6 * a * a << "sq.units" << endl;
            } else if (userchoice = 2) {
                cout << "Enter side a\n";
                cin >> a;
                cout << "Volume of cube is " << a * a * a << "cu.units" << endl;
            }
            break;
        case '3':
            cout << "Enter length, breadth, height\n";
            cin >> breadth;
            cin >> length;
            cin >> height;
            cout << "Area of cuboid is " << (length * breadth * height) << "sq.units" << endl;
            break;
        case '4':
            cout << "1-circumference\n";
            cout << "2-Area\n";
            if (userchoice = 1) {
                cout << "Enter the radius of circle\n";
                cin >> radius;
                cout << "Circumference of circle is " << 2 * PI * radius << endl;
            } else if (userchoice = 2) {
                cout << "Enter the radius of circle\n";
                cin >> radius;
                cout << "Area of circle is " << PI * radius * radius << "sq.units" << endl;
            }
            break;
        case '5':
            cout << "1-Area\n";
            cout << "2-volume\n";
            if (userchoice = 1) {
                cout << "Enter the radius of Sphere\n";
                cin >> radius;
                cout << "Area of Sphere is " << 4 * PI * radius * radius << "sq.units" << endl;
            } else if (userchoice = 2) {
                cout << "Enter the radius of Sphere\n";
                cin >> radius;
                cout << "Volume of Sphere is " << (4 / 3 * PI * radius * radius) << "cu.units" << endl;
            }
            break;
        case '6':
            cout << "1-Area\n";
            cout << "2-perimeter\n";
            if (userchoice = 1) {
                cout << "Enter length width\n";
                cin >> length;
                cin >> width;
                cout << "Area of rectangle: " << length * width << "sq.units" << endl;
            } else if (userchoice = 2) {
                cout << "Enter side\n";
                cin >> a;
                cout << "Perimeter of rectangle is " << 4 * a << "sq.units" << endl;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is certainly no C#. And you can't compare a string with switch and you should not do `userchoice = 1` because this is an assignment and not a comparison (integers could be compared by using `==`, but not strings)

Comment: Even if you fix your use of `=`, you forgot to read the user's input for the cases where you provide new options.

Answer (score 1):

**switch** statements can only execute through one **case**. It can "fall through" if you don't use breaks though. If you mean that it's not executing any of the **if** statements in the **switch** statement, it's because you're using the "assignment" operator (=) in the condition. You should be using the "is equal to" operator (==) instead.

So your **if** statements should be something like this:

```
if (userchoice == 1) {
    // ... do something ...
}
else if (userchoice == 2) {
    // ... do something else ...
}
```

Even if you do that, you have another problem that I notice. You're using the same variable in the condition of the **if** and **switch** statements. Doing it that way will make it impossible to execute some routes. You should use separate variables for both and prompt the user for both. Either that, or reassign "userchoice" to be used in the **if** statements.

Also, you're declaring "userchoice" as a char. If you declare it as a char, you should test for a char in the conditions. If not, declare it as an int.